# How to convert component of String[] or Object[] to other type

Tags: java, string

I have knowledge of wrapper class methods, but I want to know how to convert the component of String[] or Object[] to other type like int,float or Date format. for example

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvfile));
String curr;
while((scurr=br.readLine())!null) {
String[] input = scurr.split(",");
}
```

Now I want assign the component of String to primitive type(assume that my input string contains integer value)

but when I am trying to do

```
int i = input[0]
```

I am getting following suggestions:
1. change the type of i to String or
2. change the type of input to int

Is there any way to tackle the above scenario

**edit:**

I am really sorry guys, I really don't want ask duplicate questions, but after going through your answers and analyzing my scenario, I understood my mistake. So I would like to delete this post. How to do that without impacting the community please guild me

Comment: `Integer.parseInt(s)` will help you to convert string to int.

Comment: Google: "How to convert String to int in java"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Integer.parseInt()` without an issue.

```
int i = input[0] // i is an int while input[0] is a String
```

Now

```
int i=Integer.parseInt(input[0])
```

will convert `String` to `int`

[Integer.parseInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29)